# How to handle repondents mistakes in skip questions?

Tags: spss, missing-data

I have a questionnaire in which there are multiple skip questions (for example: Q1 is YES and NO and Q2 should be answered only if the respondent choose YES in Q1. Same thing apply to Q3-Q4 and Q5-6) and the problem is there are multiple repondents answer the skip question (e.g., Q2) even though they choose 'NO' in the previous question (e.g., Q1), at the same time, there are respondents who did't answer Q2 even though the choose 'YES' in Q1.

My questions are:

- Using **SPSS** and from a large data, how can I detect all those type of responds?
- If I detect these responds, then how can I deal with it? Should I delete them or what?

Comment: Just for the record, respondents are making mistakes due to a faulty survey design and web-based implementation. Based on their responses there should have been strictly controlled follow-through from page to page and item to item. Your team fup'd that up, not the respondents. You should see to fixing that for the next surveys.

Comment: @MikeHunter +1, but if many respondents answered a question they shouldn't have answered to, this is not only a potential technical issue to fix - it also challenges the idea that the question should be designed as conditional. In general, this kind of issue should be detected when pre-testing the survey on a handful of respondents.

Comment: Using SPSS will make your results more difficult for others to reproduce. There are lots of free and open source tools available these days.

Answer (score 6):

> "there are respondents who did't answer Q2 even though the choose
> 'YES' in Q1."

When respondents don't answer a question when they can answer it, this is certainly a case of [missing data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data). Unless you're in the case of an open question, you can use imputation methods to address that. You can have a look at [How should I determine what imputation method to use?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541337/how-should-i-determine-what-imputation-method-to-use) and [the many other related questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-imputation).

> multiple repondents answer the skip question (e.g., Q2) even though
> they choose 'NO' in the previous question

If the questionnaire was self-administered and a respondent answered a question they shouldn't logically respond to, then *in theory* you should ignore the specific answer they give to the question (i.e. delete it).

However, this kind of answer should raise suspicion towards the truthfulness and consistency of their other answers. You may want to check for inconsistent patterns in their other answers.

In addition, if many respondents answered a specific question when they shouldn't have, you may have an issue with the question design or validity. Respondents might be right when answering the question in spite of your instructions. Maybe there are situations you didn't think of, where people are legitimate to give an answer despite what you initially thought. Investigate it – maybe contact a couple of respondents who answered like that, to understand the rationale behind these answers. [Marielle's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/622646/164936) gives some good advice relative to the kind of things you can investigate.

If your assumptions were indeed incorrect when designing the skip questions, you shouldn't delete or ignore these answers. However, *all* the answers to these questions may end up unreliable, because of the bias introduced by the instructions you gave – i.e. some respondents could have legitimately answered the question, but didn't because unfortunately you incited them not to, so your results are biased.

> Using SPSS and from a large data, how can I detect all those type of
> responds?

As mentioned by Peter Flom in [his answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/622637/164936), your question about SPSS is software specific, so off-topic here (try asking it on https://stackoverflow.com). To give some software-agnostic advice though, in addition to Peter's advice to use some *if-else* statements (or other filters), you could crosstabulate questions and their nested counterpart to quickly estimate the number of potentially problematic answers (in your case, it would be a crosstabulation of Q1 and Q2, for example).

Answer (score 6):

If your respondents didn't follow the instructions for your questionnaire, the first thing you need to do is try and find out what happened and why.

- Look at the questionnaire again, try to take a participant's perspective. Were the instructions clear enough? Does it seem to make sense to answer the second question after a NO-answer, or is it complete nonsense? Don't just look at the wording, but also the presentation/lay-out. This should give you a first clue on how to handle the unexpected responses
- Then move to the statistics:

  - How many participants answered questions that they shouldn't have answered?
  - How many participants skipped questions that they should have answered?
  - Are these participants the same people every time?
  - Are these participants from a specific demographic group? (education level, age, literacy, personality traits, etc)
  - Are there patterns with regards to completion time? (did the people who skipped those questions complete the questionnaire faster than the others?)

All together, this should give you an idea about what happened and how much it matters for your results. Missing at random should be handled (or reported) differently than missing not at random.

As for the SPSS part, I'd probably just compute a couple of extra variables (with compute variable) for each type of mistake (with boolean operators).

Answer (score 5):

For your first point, I would guess there is something like an IF THEN statement in SPSS, but it might be easier to do it in the data source. In any case, questions about software are off topic here.

For your second point, yes, I would delete them. But look at them first! Maybe your skip questions aren't well designed. That might mean other problems, as well. (Although sometimes the problem is with the responses; I've seen some truly bizarre patterns of answers).